# Multithread file reading overhead in java

Tags: java, multithreading, io

I have a server with plenty of resources in terms of processors, storage throughput and memory for processing a huge mass of files.

I am doing some performance tests and have adapted a small java program to test the parallel reading.Code is below

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
class MultiThreadedFileRead extends Thread
{
        InputStream in;
        MultiThreadedFileRead(String fname) throws Exception
        {
                in=new FileInputStream(fname);
                this.start();
        }
        public void run()
        {
                int i=0;
                while(i!=-1)
                {
                        try
                        {
                            i=in.read();
                            //System.out.print((char)i);
                                                        continue;
                        }catch(Exception e){}
                }
                try
                {
                        in.close();
                }catch(Exception e){}
        }
        public static void main(String a[]) throws Exception
        {
                int n=[0];
                MultiThreadedFileRead fr[]=new MultiThreadedFileRead[n];
                long tim;
                tim=System.currentTimeMillis();
                for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
                        fr[i]=new MultiThreadedFileRead(a[i]);
                for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
                {
                        try
                        {
                                fr[i].join();
                        }catch(Exception e){}
                }
                System.out.println("Time Required : "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-tim)+" miliseconds.");
        }
}
```

The results seems corrects: reading 10 files in parallel (10 threads) takes about the same time as reading one file/one thread plus some overhead. *(sorry, I don't have the actual numbers here, might edit later adding it)*.

To be sure though, I'd like to know is what would be the expected, or "reasonable" overhead for opening threads for parallel reading...?

Also, I am **not** a java developer, so although the program is pretty simple, if I got something wrong please point it out.

ps. to run the program I have 10x10mb files (named tf0, tf1, tf2, etc.), and I run the test as `java MultiThreadedFileRead 10 tf*` (for 10 threads).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem might be that the **IO itself is not multithreaded**.

If you create **X** threads and they all issue a read on *IO* it will not be **X** times faster because it does the IO reads sequentially.

I have tested the code for 9 threads and for 1 thread files (100MB each). Result were 208 seconds and 94 seconds.

There are two issues with the test as I see it:

1. Reading without buffering (byte by byte) is not getting you max throughput.
2. You are creating n-1 threads in the test.

Comment: The OP doesn't have a problem. Reading 10 files in 10 threads takes just as long as reading 1 file in 1 thread (plus a little overhead). So the speed-up from using 10 threads is 10 times. His question is about this little overhead.

Comment: I ran the tests that seem to confirm my answer.

Comment: @mrVoid I see. as for the n-1,  its a bug from a small edit I've made to post here. As for performance, it isn't really the point - I just want a reproducible test. I will however chance the script into NIO as  suggested by Michael! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in researching the time it takes to fire up a thread for two main reasons:

1. It will be insignificant compared to the the amount of time it takes to read the file - unless you have some seriously empowered system.
2. The statistics you gather will be specific to the system you are testing on - move it to another system, run it on a hot/cold day and your statistics will be meaningless.

You would be better to investigate actually distributing the processes across multiple machines if you are looking for a real performance boost.

Comment: Cool, I agree, was just checking. Now, what about the answer from mrVoid? My program seem to behave as expected even though he says IO is not multithreaded...

Comment: @filippo - There is likely an amount of buffering and read-ahead cacheing going on that ensures that you see what seems to be linear scaling. If you changed to random seek/read/write you will probably begin to suffer from the linearity of disk I/O but again - it depends on your hardware. If you are working on an SSD or a NAS your timings will be different again. Premature optimisation is a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a server, you should probably use a thread pool rather than re-creating the threads. This would remove the thread creation overhead (except for a single time) and would prevent your server from going down when there are too many requests.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Also, you may want to consider non-blocking io, for a real performance boost.

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/nio-vs-io.html

When using normal reads, as @mrVoid suggested, you should use buffered readers.

And you might want to throw in some caching mechanism.